# Заполнение массива строками из файла

Tags: c#, массивы, файловая-система

написал класс для рандомной генерации фразы:

```
internal class Answerlist{
    private static string[] answers = new string[]{
        "A cane non magno saepe ingens aper tenetur.",
        "Ab aqua silente cave.",
        "Gens una sumus.",
        "Manifestum non eget probatiōne.",
        "Pro memoria."
    };

    public  static string getRandomAnswer(){
        return answers[new Random().Next(answers.Length)];
    }
}
```

хотелось бы загружать строки из файла, что-то вроде такого:

```
private  static string[] answers = File.ReadAllLines("res/latin.txt");
```

не пойму как правильно организовать код, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: ReadAllLines не работает? Это по идее правильный способ.

Comment: да всё правельно мне пишет путь не верен. как организовать путь к проекту? меня отправляют кудато в дебаг/рес. latin.txt сделал ресурсом. где-то в настройках проекта наверно

Comment: Тогда в чём вопрос? Ещё вместо `new Random().Next` используйте `Random.Shared.Next`.

Comment: Путь строится от Environment.CurrentDirectory. какой путь вам нужен, известно только вам.

Comment: Какой тип приложения - тоже надо к гадалке идти. Оформите вопрос нормально. Укажите текст ошибки и что нужно.

Comment: я сделал папку res в корне проекта и там файл latin.txt , но мне говорят что путь другой

Comment: Переложите ее в дебаг папку, где exe файл проекта лежит собраный

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory)` - вот сюда положите папку

Comment: переместил папку в дебаг. всё заработало но если я начинаю делать релис то снова ругань на путь. и чё теперь мне и в релис копию папки?

Comment: В Solution Explorer правый клик на файле > Properties (свойства) > Copy to Output Directory задать Copy if newer.

Comment: всем спасибо вопрос решён